# Defining TileSize when making WMS Request on Leaflet Web page

Tags: javascript, leaflet, wms

I am creating a web page with Leaflet to access a WMS server.
The issue I have is that I access a paying WMS server that is "counting" the number of requests I make.

In the first attempt I made, since the default tileSize was 256px each of my requests generated 16 tiles requests and so I was "deducted" 16 requests on my account.

I then tried to  modify my code as follow :

```
var wmsserver = L.tileLayer.wms('http://wmsserver/wms?', {
 layers: 'mix:precip_24h:mm' ,
 format: 'image/png',
 tileSize: window.screen.width,  
 version: '1.3.0',
 transparent: true,
});
```

Now I still have 2 requests logged, and the result on the screen is a little bit shifted.

[image: Result screenshot]

There must be a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: Without seeing any screenshots of the actual result, I'll venture to say that having non-power-of-two sizes makes the tiles overlap at the antimeridian.